# Using a dynamic UI to draw a 3d plot in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, 3d, plotly

I have a dataframe:

```
df1<-data.frame(a=rnorm(100),b=rnorm(100),c=rnorm(100),ID1=c("A","B"),ID2=(c("A","B","C","D")))
```

I am drawing a 3d plot with `plotly` by adding add_trace in a loop, like:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
df1<-data.frame(a=rnorm(100),b=rnorm(100),c=rnorm(100),ID1=c("A","B"),ID2=(c("A","B","C","D")))

test<-unique(df1$ID2)
tempt.col<-c("red","blue","green","yellow")
p<-plot_ly()
for(i in 1:length(test)){
  df2<-df1[df1$ID2==test[i],] %>%
    select(a,b,c)
  p<-add_trace(p=p,
               data = df2,
               x=~a,y=~b,z=~c,
               type="scatter3d",
               marker = list(size=5,color=tempt.col[i]),
               mode="markers"
  )
}
p
```

It works very well like:

[image]

Now I want to achieve this in shiny, I would like to generate `colourInput` based on the length of the selected ID, the ui:

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("select1","Select the ID",choices = colnames(df1[,4:5]),multiple = FALSE),
      actionButton("act1","Go"),
      uiOutput("ui1"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table1"),
      plotlyOutput("plot.3d",height = "1000px")
    )
  )
)
```

server:

```
server<-function(input,output){
  tempt.group<-reactive({
    unique(df1[,input$select1])
  })
  observeEvent(input$act1,{
    tempt.vector<-list()
    tempt.col.name<-isolate(
      vector(mode = "list",length = 2)
    )
    for(i in 1:length(tempt.group())){
      tempt.vector[[i]]<-colourpicker::colourInput(
        inputId = paste0("ColorID",i),
        label = tempt.group()[i])
      tempt.col.name[[1]][i]<-paste0("ColorID",i)
      tempt.col.name[[2]][i]<-tempt.group()[i]
    }
    output$ui1<-renderUI({
      tempt.vector
    })
    names(tempt.col.name)<-c("inputId","label")
    col.name<-reactive({
      data.frame(sapply(tempt.col.name,cbind))
    })
    
    col.df<-reactive({
      tempt.col.df<-reactiveValuesToList(input)
      data.frame(
        names = names(tempt.col.df[grepl("ColorID", names(tempt.col.df))]),
        values = unlist(tempt.col.df[grepl("ColorID", names(tempt.col.df))], use.names = FALSE)
      )
    })
    
    group.col.df<-reactive({
      merge(col.df(),col.name(),by.x="names",by.y="inputId")
    })
    
    output$table1<-renderTable(
      group.col.df()
    )
    
    pp<-reactive({
      p<-plot_ly()
      for(i in 1:length(tempt.group())){
        # col<-group.col.df()[group.col.df()[,"label"]==tempt.group()[i],"values"] ####it should be something wrong with here
        df2<-df1[df1$ID==tempt.group()[i],] %>%
          select(a,b,c)
        p<-add_trace(p=p,
                     data = df2,
                     x=~a,y=~b,z=~c,
                     type="scatter3d",
                     # marker = list(size=5,color=col[i]),  ####it should be something wrong with here
                     mode="markers"
        )
      }
      p
    })
    output$plot.3d<-renderPlotly({
      pp()
    })
    
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

The app is like:
[image]

I want to fetch the `colourInput` and pass to the color of the 3d scatter plot, but nothing works. The page either keeps refreshing or frozen,
That must be something wrong with `col<-group.col.df()[group.col.df()[,"label"]==tempt.group()[i],"values"]` and `marker = list(size=5,color=col[i])`,

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below works as intended.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
df1<-data.frame(a=rnorm(100),b=rnorm(100),c=rnorm(100),ID1=c("A","B"),ID2=(c("A","B","C","D")))

# Define UI 
ui<-fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("select1","Select the ID",choices = colnames(df1[,4:5]),multiple = FALSE),
      # actionButton("act1","Go"),
      uiOutput("myui"),
      # keep track of the last selection on all selectInput created dynamically
      
    ),
    mainPanel(
      #tableOutput("table1"),
      plotlyOutput("plot.3d",height = "1000px")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server<-function(input,output){
  rv <- reactiveValues(mygroup=0, uitaglist = list(), uilabels = list(), input_subset = list(), plotly=NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$select1, {
    newgroup <- unique(df1[,input$select1])
    rv$mygroup <- newgroup
    
    # ui tags
    rv$uitaglist <- list()
    for(i in 1:length(rv$mygroup)){
      rv$uitaglist[[i]]<-colourpicker::colourInput(
        inputId = paste0("ColorID",i),
        label = rv$mygroup[i])
      rv$uilabels[[i]] <- paste0("ColorID",i)
    }
   
  })
  
  output$myui <- renderUI({
    rv$input_subset <- rv$uitaglist
  })
  
  observe({
    rv$input_subset <- lapply(rv$uilabels, function(x) input[[x]])
    p<-plot_ly()
    for(i in 1:length(rv$mygroup)) {

      df2<-df1[df1$ID2 == rv$mygroup[i],] %>% select(a,b,c)
      p<-add_trace(p=p,
                   data = df2,
                   x=~a,y=~b,z=~c,
                   type="scatter3d",
                   marker = list(size=5,color=rv$input_subset[[i]]),
                   mode="markers"
      )
    }
    rv$plotly <- p
  })

  output$plot.3d<-renderPlotly({
    rv$plotly
  })
} # end server

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The main difficulty was to `observe` all your dynamically-generated UI inputs at once. [Turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73352718/5224236) it could be done using `observe` and `lapply`.

[image]

Observing several inputs is problematic because the error `Must use single string to index into reactivevalues` is returned by trying to index `input` by a vector or list.

Now, *Why* this can't be done out-of-the-box is a good question.

Comment: I am trying to apply to my real data !! Realy apprecate your reply, thank you very much!!

Comment: Dear @gaut, thank you very much again for you help. I have sucessfuly done it in my real data, however, after ploting this 3d plot, all the reactive values of other module in my app changed very slow, do you have any idea why this happen?

Comment: Well, how much data do you have - and how complex is your app? I guess that would best be another question to see if the app can be optimized